# nginx recv() failed (104 connection reset by peer) while sending request to upstream

Tags: nginx, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google App Engine (Flexible Environment) to deploy my application. My application is written in Flask and I am using Gunicorn. I have a requirement where a user can upload a file and I am saving that file in a GCS bucket. It worked fine for me locally but the moment I deployed it on App engine it started giving me 502 Bad Gateway.

When I looked into the logs it showed a warning first and then an error as below:

```
[warn] 34#34: *346 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000001

[error] 34#34: *346 writev() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending request to upstream,
```

So apparently it's not able to send the request. I have tried to increase my server timeout. But it did not work. Please Help!

Comment: The warning is expected and is not an issue.  How large is your file?

Comment: I even tried 10 kb file. it still gives same error.